# tSQLt How can I tell if my SPs are running in the test environment transaction?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, ssms, tsqlt

I have created several 'Constructors' for different objects in my database. These constructors will fake any tables required when creating these objects.

Unfortunately I just ran one of these constructors outside of the testing framework (and so outside a transaction) and just had to track down the renamed table to restore it.

Is there anyway I can ensure that the stored procedure is running inside a tSQLt transaction?

(I know that I can check that I am inside **any** transaction using `@@TRANSCOUNT` but want to specifically check that it is a tSQLt transaction).

Thanks.

Comment: Checking `@@TRANCOUNT` is likely to be the best that you can do; afaik there is no direct way to identify the specific block of code/database object  which opened the current transaction. Although tSQLt creates named transaction savepoints, there doesn't seem to be a way to access the savepoint names from any of the transaction-related DMVs - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178621.aspx

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the link. I'll use `@@TRANCOUNT` for now. This will at least ensure that the change is always rolled back.